# AngularJS $stateParams - Data not passing between states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, routes, angular-ui-router

I am using `$stateParams` with angular ui-router to pass in the id property of a json object to the url when employees in an employees list are clicked, so that their data is shown in the employee details page.

The url routing seems to be working, because the employee id is successfully shown in the url, but the data is not passing to the employee details state from the employee list. Employees are stored in json objects within controller 'employeesListController', in the 'employees/employeesList' state, and I need the details for the clicked employee to show in controller 'employeeDetailsController', in the 'employees/employeeDetails' state.

Example of url extension I'm getting (so it's routing correctly): `/employees/employeeDetails/21101994`.

I've looked at $state.go, but can't understand how I would implement it into this code, because I can't find a comprehensive practical example.

States:

```
.state('employees/employeesList', {
    url: '/employees/employeesList',
    templateUrl: 'pages/employees/employeesList.html',
    controller: 'employeesListController'
})

.state('employees/employeeDetails', {
    url: '/employees/employeeDetails/:employeeId',
    templateUrl: 'pages/employees/employeeDetails.html',
    controller: ('employeesDetailsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', function($scope, $stateParams) {
        $scope.employeeId = $stateParams.employeeId;
    }])
})
```

-

'employeesListController':

```
app.controller('employeesListController', function($scope) {
$scope.active = 'active';

$scope.sortByAllDepartments = '+lastName';

var employees = [
    {
        id: '21101994',
        firstName: 'Employee',
        lastName: 'One'
    },
    {
        id: '22071958',
        firstName: 'Employee',
        lastName: 'Two'
    },
];

$scope.employees = employees;
})
```

-

HTML incl. ui-sref link:

```
<li class="collection-item col-xs-12" data-ng-repeat="employee in employees | orderBy: sortByAllDepartments | filter:searchAllDepartments">

    <a ui-sref="employees/employeeDetails({employeeId: employee.id})" class="employeeLink"></a>

        <div>

            <p data-ng-show="employee.firstName || employee.lastName" class="title">{{employee.firstName}} {{employee.lastName}}</p>

            <p data-ng-show="!employee.firstName" class="title">(No Data)</p>

            <p data-ng-show="!employee.lastName" class="title">(No Data)</p>

etc......
```

Comment: How are you getting the values of employees in list page? You are only sending the employeeId to details page. Is it possible to get the details of employee from id?

Comment: I've shown this. The list page, uses the employeesListController controller and uses ng-repeat for list items to bind the data

Comment: But how will you get the details of the employee in details page? What you have shown is for list page.

Comment: I see. I've just accessed the data properties the same way, using javascript selectors (example: <p>{{employee.firstName}}</p>) etc.

Comment: Your details controller doesn't have access to name etc... The only thing you are passing to details controller is employeeId. How are you getting firstName from id?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking how to do. How do I get the other object properties based on the id?

Comment: You can use a service to share the data instead of this approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153614/discussion-between-nick-and-vivz).

Answer (score 1):

The controller declaration for your `employees/employeeDetails` is wrong. It should be like:

```
.state('employees/employeeDetails', {
    url: '/employees/employeeDetails/:employeeId',
    templateUrl: 'pages/employees/employeeDetails.html',
    controller:  function($scope, $stateParams) {
        $scope.employeeId = $stateParams.employeeId;
    })
})
```

If you need a named controller, you can achieve by creating a new controller like:

```
app.controller('employeeDetailsController', function($scope, $stateParams) {
        $scope.employeeId = $stateParams.employeeId;
})
```

And in your state config:

```
.state('employees/employeeDetails', {
    url: '/employees/employeeDetails/:employeeId',
    templateUrl: 'pages/employees/employeeDetails.html',
    controller: 'employeeDetailsController
})
```

[Official Documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#controllers)

Comment: This removes the named 'employeeDetailsController' controller, and also doesn't work

Comment: There is no controller with the name `employeeDetailsController ` in the code you posted. Any way see the updated answer for named controller.